# Laravel Bus Batch pending jobs is negative

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, shopify

I'm trying to load shopify products through cache and im using `Redis::throttle` to prevent rate limit in shopify. My problem is I put all the process of fetching in a `Batch` and it returns a **negative** no. of **pending jobs**.

Here's the batch info.
[image]

and here's my approach

public function load(Request $request, Sample $sample)
{

```
    return DB::transaction(function () use ($sample) {
        $batch = Bus::batch([])->dispatch();

            $since_id = 0;

            while ($since_id >= 0) {
                $fetchedProducts = (new ShopifyProduct(
                    $sample->shopify_domain,
                    $sample->shopify_info['access_token'])
                )
                ->getById($since_id)
                ->then(function ($data) {
                    return $data['products'];
                }, function () {
                    return [];
                })
                ->wait();

                if (collect($fetchedProducts)->count() == 0) break;

                $lastProduct = Arr::last($fetchedProducts);
                $since_id = $lastProduct['id'];

                collect($fetchedProducts)
                    ->each(function ($shopifyProduct) use($merchant, &$batch) {
                        $batch->add(new CacheProducts($shopifyProduct, $sample));
                    });
            }
        

        return $this->okResponse(['batch_id' => $batch->id])
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
    });
}
```

and here's the job

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Redis::throttle("shopify-cache")->allow(30)->every(60)->block(70)->then(function () {
        (new Metafield(
                $this->merchant->shopify_domain,
                $this->merchant->shopify_info['access_token']
            )
        )
        ->get($this->shopifyProduct['id'], 'products')
        ->then(function ($data) {
            $this->shopifyProduct['metafields'] = $data['metafields'];

            $cacheProducts = Cache::tags($this->merchant->name)->get('products') ?? [];

            array_push($cacheProducts, $this->shopifyProduct);

            Cache::tags($this->merchant->name)->put('products', $cacheProducts, now()->addHour());

        }, function ($e) {
        })
        ->wait();
    }, function () {
        return $this->release(10);
    });
}
```

Comment: "I put all the process of fetching in a Batch and it returns a negative no. of pending jobs." What does this mean? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: You can see at my screenshot that the pendingJobs data is negative

Comment: My problem is why it became negative, what are the cause and factors. Is it because of failed jobs that are trying to retry? I don't have any idea right now why it became negative.

Comment: Do not add pictures to your question. Copy and paste text, and properly describe what that information represents.

Answer (score 5):

You need to refactor you code which is dispatching the jobs for better understanding what exactly you are doing and to simplify your code.

Besides of that, you are dispatching an empty batch and later in the loop you are adding jobs to the batch with `$batch->add()` which is totally fine, but you are passing the `&$batch` variable in your closure, which, I think is not working as you expect.

And what is `$fetchedProducts` returning? you are fetching it by ID, but the lastId is the id of the last item in that array, isn't that the same id then?

I think it will help you if you split your code in peaces and debug every part to check if the job batches are working properly:

1. First make sure your job's handle is doing nothing but directly returning (`return;`) so you can first test your `load` class.

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
     return;

     // All of the original code in this method you can comment out, for quicker testing.
   }
   ```
2. Just cut your `load()` method in pieces, so you can step by step check if every line of code is working as you expect.
3. Refactor your code to better understand what is happening. I've made some changes in the hope this code will be somewhat more readable;

   ```
    return DB::transaction(function () use ($sample) {
        $jobs = [];

        // Fetch all products (if there are too many products, you may use paginated results)
        $fetchedProducts = (new ShopifyProduct(
            $sample->shopify_domain,
            $sample->shopify_info['access_token'])
        )
        // Can you explain how $since_id can be different for each product if you are fetching products by that same id?
        //->getById($since_id)
        ->then(function ($data) {
            return $data['products'];
        }, function () {
            return [];
        })->wait();

        if (collect($fetchedProducts)->empty()) {
            return $this->okResponse(['message' => 'No products to process.'])
                ->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
        }

        collect($fetchedProducts)
            ->each(function ($shopifyProduct) use($merchant, &$jobs) {
                $jobs[] = new CacheProducts($shopifyProduct, $sample)
            });

        // After all jobs are added, we can dispatch them.
        $batch = Bus::batch($jobs)->dispatch();

        return $this->okResponse(['batch_id' => $batch->id])
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
    });
   ```

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work. I solved it by using custom table to store jobs and by moving all loops in the job itself. I didn't used laravel bus batch because it still persist even i did increase the aws sqs server.

Comment: What was the problem with aws sqs server? And isn't it a bit overkill to create your custom jobs table? It should work with the job structure laravel is providing. 

And can you tell me how you dispatch those jobs now to fix the problem, I think many can learn from it (myself included). Thanks!